# Can I track changes to a web form using webtrends?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, webtrends

Does anyone know of a way to track changes to a web form, i.e. select or text field using webtrends?

I know Google Analytics has similar functionality, can this be done in WebTrends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webtrends has Javascript click tracking so you'd have to add Javascript onChange or onClick events to whatever you need to track.

Since web forms don't typically trigger the Webtrends link tracking, you have to use the dcsMultiTrack function, passing the variables that need to be tracked.

For example, you might use the following to track the URL that you're on and the fact that a particular field was clicked:

onClick="onclick="dcsMultiTrack('DCS.dcssip','www.domain.com','DCS.dcsuri','/yourpage', 'WT.ti','formfield1','WT.dl','1');"

Note that the WT.dl parameter should be set so you don't count extra page views. Also note that the WT.ti parameter is used for automatically tracking this as a link click. If you need more granularity, you can always define another variable (for example, "formname) and configure Webtrends to report on that as another dimension.